# Prove that the sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+x_{n}}$, with $x_0>-1$, converges and has a limit

Tags: limits

> Prove that the sequence converges and has a limit: 
>   $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+x_{n}},\quad\text{with}\; x_0 > - 1$$.
>   I found the limit, it is equal to $$
> \frac { 2 } { 1 + \sqrt { 5 } }
> $$ , it remains to prove the existence of the limit.
>   I tried to prove that the limit exists according to Cauchy, considered the difference $x _ { n + 1 } -  x _ { n } $, but nothing worked.

Comment: I don't know how I would even use l'Hopital on this, to be honest. It's not a method commonly used on recursive sequences. Also, what is $x_0$?

Comment: $x _ { 0 } > - 1$

Comment: Hint: find a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $x_0$ on which $x \mapsto 1/(1+x)$ is a well-defined contraction mapping.

Comment: Show that this is Cauchy?

Comment: One idea: Try to find an expression for $x_n$ of the form 
$$
x_n = \frac{Ax+B}{Bx+C}
$$

Comment: @MattiP. I tried to do this, I got A, B, C and D equal to the Fibonacci numbers, I found the limit, but I can not prove why it exists

Comment: @xuq01 ,To prove that the difference of neighboring members of the sequence is infinitesimal?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I do not quite understand what you wanted to say

Comment: @Yaroslav: Since comments are easily overlooked, you should [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3386473/edit) to add the details of what you've tried (eg, how you got the Fibonacci $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and what value you found for the limit). This can save potential answerers from wasting time (theirs and yours) duplicating your effort and/or telling you things you already know.

Comment: @Yaroslav I've expanded my comment into a full solution. But no, to show a sequence is Cauchy it does *not* suffice to show that that difference of consecutive terms goes to $0$. For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge, but the difference of two consecutive partial sums does go to $0$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I unfortunately do not know what is the Banach Fixed Point Theorem

Comment: @MattiP. Do not tell me what to do next?

Comment: Well you should be using the answers and comments as hints only. You are the one who hasn't expanded the question: if you had added more [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) when you first asked the problem, we wouldn't need to ask you so much to find out what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand upon my comment for clarity.

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be the map $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$. $f$ is a contraction mapping on the complete metric space $[0,\infty)$ because $\lvert f'(x) \rvert = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \leq 1$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, with equality if and only if $x = 0$. By the Banach Fixed Point Theorem‚ $f$ has a unique fixed point, which is the limit of the sequence $z, f(z), f(f(z)), \dots$ for any $z \in [0,\infty)$. Since $f(x_0) \in [0,\infty)$ and $f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$ for all $n$, we see that $x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots$ converges to the unique fixed point of $f$. By inspection, this fixed point is $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.